# Raphael JS on rect click redirect to url takes the last url for all rectangles

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, raphael, rectangles

I am trying to iterate over the list and create the rectangle boxes, and on click of each user should be redirected to specific page, though struggling to understand the click handler. Please help me to refine below code, so that it redirects to corresponding url instead of the last one. (I think its my lack of knowledge in JS itself.)

```
       var items = [{'url': 'http://google.com'}, {'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com'}];
       var bh = 120;
       var bw = 120;
       var br = 8;
       var start_x = 100;
       var start_y = 80;
       r = Raphael("holder", 840, 780)
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
          group = r.set()
          group.push(r.rect(start_x, start_y, bh, bw, br));
          start_x = start_x+200;
          group[0].node.onclick = function(){
             alert(items[i].url);
          };
       }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpatel/jEcNK/1/)

Above code is kind of version what I am working on and it renders multiple rects on SVG, the problem I am running into is on click of the rect, it returns the last one only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's one variable called `i`, and after the loop is over its value is `items.length`. You need to remember the correct value for each node. Try this:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
      ...
      var rect = r.rect(start_x, start_y, bh, bw, br);
      rect.node.setAttribute('data-index', i);
      group.push(rect);
      ...
      rect.node.onclick = function(event) {
         alert(items[event.target.getAttribute('data-index')].url);
      };
   }
```